# Database not in open state in ODI12c - Repository Creation Utility

Tags: database, oracle, repository, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-data-integrator

I am getting the following error, when I am trying to create repository in ODI through Repository Creation Utility

[image]

ERROR - RCU-6005 Unable to execute sql query.
CAUSE - RCU-6005 Database not in open state.
ACTION - RCU-6005 Make sure that the database is open.

How can I solve this issue

Comment: Make sure the repository database is running before you run the RCU.

Comment: It is running. but still getting the error

Comment: The error implies that it isn't fully open and ready to accept connections.

Comment: @ArjithBabu Your container database might be running but not your Pluggable database.Check the status of pluggable database `ORCLPDB`